# Mulesoft --- the occurrence of a in payload using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

the occurrence of a in payload using dataweave mule

Answer (score 1):

`scan` returns an array of substrings that match a regular expression.

So something like
`sizeOf ("test string test" scan "test")` will return the number of occurances of "test" from the string "test string test"

Answer (score 0):

Expression component can be used to find if particular character exists in a string. Below result is stored in a flow variable which can be accessed later in the flow.

```
 <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[flowVars.index="test example test".indexOf("a");]]></expression-component>
```